# How do I transform triangle polygons into quads?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to learn Blender. I started modeling this "easy" exercise, but I can´t make step 5 in the process, please tell me how do this. I've got everything up to this step.

Thanks!

Marko.

([Full size image](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?260408-Jabulani-Teamgeist-and-Starball-quot-Soccer-Ball-Series-quot-%28Updated%29))
[image: the exercice of modeling]

[the model I done in blender](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kf7entgz56qgwgr/balonestrellas.blend)

[image: the fail step...]

Comment: I'm not sure how to help. What are you trying, and how does it "not work?" Are you using the command, but it doesn't seem to do anything, or are you having trouble understanding what steps to take to make number 5 (I can't say that I understand exactly what number 5 means either)?

Comment: Hi, first sorry for my english... When try to make the command to triangle like said in step 5 nothing happen... subdivide (W) the edge of triangles but connect vertex tool don´t work to make this... maybe one step losing in the process...

Comment: Adding another image to try to explain my question...

Comment: Your title is not relevant to your question. I'd suggest change your title. Perhaps, you can consider "How do I transform triangle polygons into quads?" Afterall, that what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done within 10 secs. I've seen this tutorial two years ago. I'm sure you can speed up the whole workflow with the new powerful tools developed since then. :) My suggestion for step 1 to 5 on this exercise can be seen below in briefly 3 steps. However, if you just want to focus on the exact question, just jump to Step 3:

**P.S.**: Since you said you are new to Blender, I tried to reproduce every detailed step, so it may look a bit long, but all operations can be done in a flash if you get it then.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: ...WOW!!! is amazing how easy you show the all process... thank you very very much for your help... I post the final result...

Comment: I've updated another choice for Step 1, which is almost accurate, and much much faster. Fyi.

Comment: Well finally finished this tutorial, thanks to all to help me to understand the tools to modeling in Blender... Go for the next, some tips?. 
![Before spherize](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ryld5urt0d6jeyd/Capturafinal.PNG).

![with cast modifier](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e10aerwqao9lq10/Capturafinal2.PNG).

Comment: Well, I don't think we should expand the talk here, since it's sort of off topic. But here, two points: You shouldn't do step 8 before step 7; and you have to apply the modifiers before going ahead. If you still got question, welcome to ask as a new one then. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what the tutorial want's you to do with those tools. However, you can use a few different tools to do create the same topology:

1. Select each edge of the triangle and subdivide it (<kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide):
   [image]
2. Select the face and poke it (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).
   [image]
3. Turn them into quads with the face tool (<kbd>F</kbd>):
   [image]

Comment: Thank you very very much... I sudivide all edges at same time and make another kind of divisions...follow your advise and make triangles to quads like tutorial..thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have another way to do this more "easy"?..thanks again.